# Access named controller's method from directive's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to call some methods from parent controller defined with `Controller as` syntax from directive's template but I can't do it with isolated scope. I could write my directive without isolated scope but in this case I can't reuse it.

Simple example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('myController', function() {
        var result_el = document.getElementById("log");
        this.log = function(text) {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerHTML = text;
            result_el.appendChild(p);
        }
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            template: '<button ng-click="mCtrl.log(123)">Click me!</button>'
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController as mCtrl">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Is it possible to call parent controller's functions from directive's template?

Comment: pass the function into the directive. e.g. `scope: {myFunc: '&'}`

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('myController', function() {
        var result_el = document.getElementById("log");
        this.log = function(text) {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerHTML = text;
            result_el.appendChild(p);
        }
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {myFunc: '&'},

            template: '<button ng-click="myFunc()">Click me!</button>'
        }
    });
```

and your template as

```
<my-directive myFunc="log(123)"></my-directive>
```